# Java going through a list?

Tags: java, arrays, list

How would I make java go through a list in order?

Example: Im trying to get 2 diff coords but If I make it load 1 then it still needs to load 2 ints, so I'm making it load 2 but if its random it could choose random coords and screw up, BUT if I make it go in order, both coord lists will remain in order and it will work, how would I do this?

Comment: At the moment I have


player.getActionSender().sendCreateObject(randomElement);
But it need's 6 int's.
ex:player.getActionSender().sendCreateObject(38660, 0, 4321, 1234, 0, 10);
But the only way we've figured it out was to make 2 public classes ex: player.getActionSender().sendCreateObject(38660, 0, randomElementX, randomElementX, 0, 10);

But now it's going to like 9 random coords rather than 4 designated coords, but If it went through a list it would continue going to the designated coords, What I'm trying to say Is I need it to go through a list non randomely.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list you can iterate its elements in order using its Iterator...

```
List<Integer> myCoords = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myCoords.add(10);
myCoords.add(20);
Iterator<Integer> myListIterator = someList.iterator(); 
while (myListIterator.hasNext()) {
    Integer coord = myListIterator.next();     
}
```

[Java List Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

[Java Iterator Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)

Comment: why `iterator` and not `foreach`? foreach seems better IMHO

Comment: No obvious reason other than foreach uses the iterator and iterators provide safe removal of elements.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if: you have `n` element `collection` of type `Integer` instances, and you want a random size `m` element permutation; where `m <= n`.

Basically you are looking for `java.util.Collections.shuffle()` method.

```
    List<Integer> nrs = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 3, 5, 6, 9, 12 });
    Collections.shuffle(nrs);
```